# I am trying to train my model with different types of fruits

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train my model with different types of fruits, But i am getting the same prediction what ever the image given,  i am usually getting only one result,

In the end my model gives always same prediction can you please help

```
"""
Created on Sat Sep 13 22:26:33 2020

@author: thummago
"""
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'gopi_cnn_training_data',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'gopi_cnn_test_data',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=32)
print(training_set)
cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[64,64,3]))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='softmax')) 
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
cnn.fit(x = training_set, validation_data = test_set, epochs = 25)
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('validation_set to check the model/0_100.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = cnn.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result == 0:
    prediction = 'ApplRed' 
elif result == 1:
    prediction = 'AppleBraeburn'
elif result == 2:
    prediction = 'AppleBraeburn'
elif result == 3:
    prediction = 'Apricot'
elif result == 4:
    prediction = 'Avocado'
elif result == 5:
    prediction = 'Banana'
elif result == 6:
    prediction = 'Cherry1'
elif result == 7:
    prediction = 'Clementine'
elif result == 8:
    prediction = 'Eggplant'
elif result == 9:
    prediction = 'Grape White'
elif result == 10:
    prediction = 'Hazelnut'
elif result == 11:
    prediction = 'Kiwi'
elif result == 12:
    prediction =  'Mango'
elif result == 13:
    prediction = 'Orange'
elif result == 14:
    prediction = 'Papaya'
elif result == 15:
    prediction = 'Pineapple'
elif result == 16:
    prediction = 'Pomegranate'
elif result == 17:
    prediction = 'Potato Red'
elif result == 18:
    prediction = 'Strawberry'
elif result == 19:
    prediction = 'Tomato1'
elif result == 20:
    prediction = 'Watermelon'
else:
    prediction = 'WrongFruit'
print(prediction
```

And i get accuracy for all the Epochs

```
Found 10349 images belonging to 21 classes.
Found 3466 images belonging to 21 classes.
<keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x0000028ABB26AC48>
Train for 324 steps, validate for 109 steps
Epoch 1/25
324/324 [==============================] - 51s 159ms/step - loss: 14.6031 - accuracy: 0.0476 - val_loss: 14.6031 - val_accuracy: 0.0476
Epoch 2/25
105/324 [========>.....................] - ETA: 54s - loss: 14.6031 - accuracy: 0.0476
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the loss does not change? This is because using a softmax activation with only one output neuron always produces a constant output of 1.0. You need to set the number of neurons at the output layer to the number of classes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) activation function on your output layer with only one node. Softmaxing a vector of length 1 will *always* return 1.

When building a classifier neural network that can choose exactly one of *n* options, you should make your output layer have *n* nodes and use the softmax activation. In order for this to work, you'll have to [one-hot-encode](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) your target data. You'll also have to change your loss to `categorical_crossentropy`.

Here's a [short tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/solve-the-mnist-image-classification-problem-9a2865bcf52a). Note that he accomplishes one-hot-encoding using Keras' `to_categorical` function.